# Gravitee docker-compose setup, how to install a previous version and where do I see the current installed version

Tags: docker, docker-compose, upgrade, versioning, gravitee

For my Gravitee setup, I am using the docker-compose file from the official documentation. However I want to simulate a version upgrade, so I would like to install a previous version and then upgrade it to the newest one for example. In the docker-compose file I see the APIM_VERSION 3 as the major version number, but I don't see the minor version number. I guess it will be the newest but where do I see it?

And I am quite sure, there should be a similar docker-compose file for previous versions, could you help me to navigate to them?

```yaml
version: '3.5'

networks:
  frontend:
    name: frontend
  storage:
    name: storage

volumes:
  data-elasticsearch:
  data-mongo:

services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:${MONGODB_VERSION:-3.6}
    container_name: gio_apim_mongodb
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - data-mongo:/data/db
      - ./logs/apim-mongodb:/var/log/mongodb
    networks:
      - storage

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${ELASTIC_VERSION:-7.17.7}
    container_name: gio_apim_elasticsearch
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - data-elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    environment:
      - http.host=0.0.0.0
      - transport.host=0.0.0.0
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - xpack.monitoring.enabled=false
      - cluster.name=elasticsearch
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile: 65536
    networks:
      - storage

  gateway:
    image: graviteeio/apim-gateway:${APIM_VERSION:-3}
    container_name: gio_apim_gateway
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
      - elasticsearch
    volumes:
      - ./logs/apim-gateway:/opt/graviteeio-gateway/logs
    environment:
      - gravitee_management_mongodb_uri=mongodb://mongodb:27017/gravitee?serverSelectionTimeoutMS=5000&connectTimeoutMS=5000&socketTimeoutMS=5000
      - gravitee_ratelimit_mongodb_uri=mongodb://mongodb:27017/gravitee?serverSelectionTimeoutMS=5000&connectTimeoutMS=5000&socketTimeoutMS=5000
      - gravitee_reporters_elasticsearch_endpoints_0=http://elasticsearch:9200
    networks:
      - storage
      - frontend

  management_api:
    image: graviteeio/apim-management-api:${APIM_VERSION:-3}
    container_name: gio_apim_management_api
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    links:
      - mongodb
      - elasticsearch
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
      - elasticsearch
    volumes:
      - ./logs/apim-management-api:/opt/graviteeio-management-api/logs
    environment:
      - gravitee_management_mongodb_uri=mongodb://mongodb:27017/gravitee?serverSelectionTimeoutMS=5000&connectTimeoutMS=5000&socketTimeoutMS=5000
      - gravitee_analytics_elasticsearch_endpoints_0=http://elasticsearch:9200
      - gravitee_environments=dev
      - gravitee_environments_dev_name=dev
    networks:
      - storage
      - frontend

  management_ui:
    image: graviteeio/apim-management-ui:${APIM_VERSION:-3}
    container_name: gio_apim_management_ui
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8084:8080"
    depends_on:
      - management_api
    environment:
      - MGMT_API_URL=http://localhost:8083/management/organizations/DEFAULT/environments/dev/
    volumes:
      - ./logs/apim-management-ui:/var/log/nginx
    networks:
      - frontend

  portal_ui:
    image: graviteeio/apim-portal-ui:${APIM_VERSION:-3}
    container_name: gio_apim_portal_ui
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8085:8080"
    depends_on:
      - management_api
    environment:
      - PORTAL_API_URL=http://localhost:8083/portal/environments/dev
    volumes:
      - ./logs/apim-portal-ui:/var/log/nginx
    networks:
      - frontend
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by myself. It is actually quite straight forward. On the Gravitee Changelog section of the doucmentation(https://docs.gravitee.io/apim/3.x/apim_changelog.html), you just have to look up a specific version. Than change all the APIM_VERSION:-3 to APIM_VERSION:- and run the container with

`docker-compose up -d`

To upgrade Gravitee APIM, change again the APIM_VERSION tags and execute the commands:

`docker-compose down`

and

`docker-compose up -d`